# Convert vector to a specific matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

For given vector with values from `y0` to `yT` I have to create following matrix:

```
1  y(P-1)  y(P-2) ... y(0)
1  y(P)    y(P-1) ... y(1)
1  y(P+1)  y(P)   ... y(2)
.   .       .     ...  .
.   .       .     ...  .
.   .       .     ...  .
1  y(T-1)  y(T-2) ... y(T-p)
```

P means y(P) is a linear combination of P previous y's.

P is given (for example 100).

Is there any matlab function for this?

function to get the right `y` for given `i,j` is

```
getAIJ = @(i, j) y(p+(-(i+1))+(j-1));
```

So I just need to apply this function for every cell in matrix except the first column. Is there any *matlab-way* to do this? I am not sure how to use arrayfun on this.

Comment: Assume a small input and tell us the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`buffer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/buffer.html) in signal processing toolbox. In this case

```
yy = buffer(y, P, P-1)';
```